# How to register sparse encoding model in AWS OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, semantic-search

I'm trying to deploy the pretrained model `amazon/neural-sparse/opensearch-neural-sparse-encoding-v1` on AWS OpensSearch to use it for Neural Sparse Search but it doesn't seem to work.

The full request:

```
POST /_plugins/_ml/models/_register
{
    "name": "amazon/neural-sparse/opensearch-neural-sparse-encoding-doc-v1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "model_group_id": "<group-id>",
    "description": "This is a neural sparse encoding model: It transfers text into sparse vector, and then extract nonzero index and value to entry and weights. It serves only in ingestion and customer should use tokenizer model in query.",
    "model_format": "TORCH_SCRIPT",
    "function_name": "SPARSE_ENCODING",
    "model_content_hash_value": "9a41adb6c13cf49a7e3eff91aef62ed5035487a6eca99c996156d25be2800a9a",
    "url":  "https://artifacts.opensearch.org/models/ml-models/amazon/neural-sparse/opensearch-neural-sparse-encoding-doc-v1/1.0.0/torch_script/opensearch-neural-sparse-encoding-doc-v1-1.0.0-torch_script.zip"
}
```

Which causes OpenSearch to return the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "To upload custom model user needs to enable allow_registering_model_via_url settings. Otherwise please use opensearch pre-trained models."
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "To upload custom model user needs to enable allow_registering_model_via_url settings. Otherwise please use opensearch pre-trained models."
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

When I try to set the `allow_registering_model_via_url` to `true`, I get the next one:

Full request:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "persistent": {
        "plugins.ml_commons.allow_registering_model_via_url": true
    }
}
```

Error:

```
{
  "Message": "Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."
}
```

I suspect AWS doesn't allow updating that settings.

Any ideas on how the model can be deployed?

Thank you!

*Notes*:

- Using OpenSearch 2.11 (latest)
- The list of OpenSearch pretrained models: https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/ml-commons-plugin/pretrained-models/#sparse-encoding-models

**SOLUTION**

I got an answer on the OpenSearch forum: https://forum.opensearch.org/t/how-to-register-sparse-encoding-model-in-aws-opensearch/17112